# Strange shaking of the output of TreeForm

Tags: front-end, trees

When I execute the following:

```
TreeForm[Hold[Plus[1, 2]]]
```

I get the expected output.  But when I execute

```
With[{f = #1 + 2*#2 &}, TreeForm[Hold[f[1, 2]]]]
```

the output shakes like crazy.

Is this a bug in Mathematica 11.1.1 on the latest version Windows 10?

Comment: There's some dynamic formatting which causes the bounce because `ImageSize` is `Automatic`. If you give it an explicit value there's no issue. Try, e.g. ``With[{f = #1 + 2*#2 &}, TreeForm[Hold[f[1, 2]], ImageSize -> 500]]``

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!  The explicit numerical size does stabilise the output.  (For the record, `ImageSize -> Medium` does not solve the problem.)